# ASP.NET Chart. Binding 2 String Columns to XValueMember? (First + Last Name)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-charts, microsoft-chart-controls

DB Query returns First and Last name as separate columns:

[image]

The control is bound to First name only right now.

[image]

What's the syntax to bind the series to First + Last name?

I know I can do it in the code behind but I want to know if it can be done in the asp markup?

Comment: I was recently trying to do the same thing.  I eventually gave up and just made a new variable for Full Name in the backend

Comment: @urnotsam i'm trying to avoid that